# React toggle tri-state component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've came across [this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-checkbox-indeterminate), which helped me this as far as I've got. Though, I'm trying to hack together a *simple* status component that instead of a checkbox, is just a div with styling to make it appear as a tiny dot that toggles between three strings, `offline`, `wip` and `online` onClick! Changing just the color upon change of state. (Practically speaking, I'll set an array of objects as offline and if toggled differently I'll store that preference.)

[image]

I'm just stuck trying to move away from a checkbox, I'll show you what I mean:

```js
const STATUS_STATES = {
  Online: "online",
  Wip: "wip",
  Offline: "offline",
};

function SomePage() {

  const [status, setStatus] = useState(STATUS_STATES.Offline);


  const handleChange = () => {
    let updatedChecked;

    if (status === STATUS_STATES.Online) {
      updatedChecked = STATUS_STATES.Offline;
    } else if (status === STATUS_STATES.Offline) {
      updatedChecked = STATUS_STATES.Wip;
    } else if (status === STATUS_STATES.Wip) {
      updatedChecked = STATUS_STATES.Online;
    }

    setStatus(updatedChecked);
  };

  
  const Status = ({ value, onChange }) => {
    const checkboxRef = React.useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
      if (value === STATUS_STATES.Online) {
        console.log("online")
        checkboxRef.current.checked = true;
        checkboxRef.current.indeterminate = false;
      } else if (value === STATUS_STATES.Offline) {
        console.log("offline")
        checkboxRef.current.checked = false;
        checkboxRef.current.indeterminate = false;
      } else if (value === STATUS_STATES.Wip) {
        console.log("wip")
        checkboxRef.current.checked = false;
        checkboxRef.current.indeterminate = true;
      }
    }, [value]);

    return (
      <label>

        <input ref={checkboxRef} type="checkbox" onChange={onChange} />
        {/* I need to replace the line above with the line below */}
        {/* while escaping the label element it's wrapped within */}
        <div
          className={
            (value === "offline" && "offline") ||
            (value === "wip" && "wip") ||
            (value === "online" && "online")
          }
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </label>
    );
  };
  return (
      <>
        <Status value={status} onChange={handleChange} />

        <p>Is checked? {status}</p>
      </>
  )
}
```

```css
.status{
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #ee4f4f;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Any advice to approach this more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tidies it up quite a bit

codebox: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-gareth-7qvko?file=/src/App.js:0-1050

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const STATUS_STATES = ["Online", "Wip", "Offline"];
const STATUS_COLORS = ["green", "orange", "red"];

const Dot = ({ color, onClick }) => (
  <div
    onClick={onClick}
    style={{ borderRadius: 5, height: 10, width: 10, background: color }}
  />
);

const Main = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = () => {
    const newStatus = (status + 1) % STATUS_STATES.length;
    setStatus(newStatus);
  };

  const text = STATUS_STATES[status];

  return (
    <>
      <Dot onClick={handleClick} color={STATUS_COLORS[status]} />
      <div onClick={handleClick}>{text}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

You will see to loop through the statuses, I have put them through in an array, and used the remainder operator to get the next index.

The useEffect logic only needed a simple if for each value which has been written in short hand which (I think) is more readable for variables.

You will also notice the onclick on the checkbox input is wrapped in a timeout with a 0ms wait. This is a workaround because I couldnt prevent the default checkbox behaviour from happening. This ensures the click handling is run after the native logic.

I also reduced your array to just an array of strings - This was just to simplify the example.

Comment: That's very nice of you, helps me understand the gist of things! Though, I am still stuck trying to avoid a checkbox rather than a stylized div! The whole ```checkboxRef``` ordeal is throwing me off!

Comment: Nps. Ill add the dot to the example that changes color to show you how to stylize a div based on your state. Are you trying to make something that resembles a checkbox or just a dot thats color switches?

Comment: So close to being the perfect answer, I just need that checkbox gone!

Comment: Right. Ive added in the dot. All of the styles in the example are inline but you're css looks fine you will just add a className attribute to the div in the Dot component. I think for the color it is better doing it line, but thats my preference. Ha ill remove the checkbox then :)

Comment: :D It's funny how simple it became, thank you very much. Betters my understanding, truly!